# How can I position elements under each other when I make the window smaller?

Tags: html, css

I am trying that the images adapt themselves to the size of the window. If there is not enough width then the elements should go down. I have tried with position static, relative, fixed and absolute on the different classes but none works.

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/scribble_light.png) ;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    min-width: 800px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

#columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 15px;
    column-fill: auto;
}

.pin {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #FEFEFE;
    border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
    margin: 0 2px 15px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #F9F9F9);
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}

.pin img {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.pin p {
    font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
    #columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
    #columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 5;
        -moz-column-count: 5;
        column-count: 5;
    }
}

#columns:hover .pin:not(:hover) {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="columns">
        <div class="pin">
            <img src="http://help.1stanswer.de/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=im:detail:beispiel_dokument_vorlage_ohne_platzhalter.png" />
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, 
                ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
                Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="pin">
            <img src="http://siliconangle.com/files/2013/08/Stock-Market-Chart2.jpg" />
            <p>
                Donec a fermentum nisi. 
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="pin">
            <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/6/6f3nXse.png" />
            <p>
                Nullam eget lectus augue. Donec eu sem sit amet ligula 
                faucibus suscipit. Suspendisse rutrum turpis quis nunc 
                convallis quis aliquam mauris suscipit.
            </p>
        </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML structure as well

Comment: Done. I replaced the images with random stock images of different lenght ala pinterest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a `column-width` on your `#columns` element in combination with the `column-count` property to define a maximum number of columns and a minimum width for each.  Also remove the `min-width` property on your `.wrapper` element.

At the appropriate width, the wrapper will allow the columns to stack horizontally up to a maximum of 3 wide.  At smaller widths, the `column-width` property determines the point at which the wrapper forces them to wrap to a newline.

Source: https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/#article-header-id-4

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Bendrick92/8df15zsr/

```css
body {
    background: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/scribble_light.png) ;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

#columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 15px;
    column-fill: auto;
    -webkit-column-width: 150px;
    -moz-column-width: 150px;
    column-width: 150px;
}

.pin {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #FEFEFE;
    border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
    margin: 0 2px 15px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #F9F9F9);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}

.pin img {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.pin p {
    font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
}

#columns:hover .pin:not(:hover) {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="columns">
        <div class="pin">
            <img src="http://help.1stanswer.de/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=im:detail:beispiel_dokument_vorlage_ohne_platzhalter.png" />
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, 
                ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
                Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="pin">
            <img src="http://siliconangle.com/files/2013/08/Stock-Market-Chart2.jpg" />
            <p>
                Donec a fermentum nisi. 
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="pin">
            <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/6/6f3nXse.png" />
            <p>
                Nullam eget lectus augue. Donec eu sem sit amet ligula 
                faucibus suscipit. Suspendisse rutrum turpis quis nunc 
                convallis quis aliquam mauris suscipit.
            </p>
        </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

960px in the code below can be changed for any value appropriate for your page

```
@media (max-width: 960px) {
    #columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
    }
    .pin {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A grid system could be useful for you to solve this kind of issues.

Bootstrap has one: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Also: http://purecss.io/grids/